# From $\Pr[A\cap B]$ and $\Pr[\bar{A}\cap B]$ deduce $\Pr[A]$

Tags: probability

Let $A$ and $B$ be two events such that $\Pr[A\cap B]=0.2$ and $0.3<\Pr[\bar{A}\cap B]<0.4$. Find $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a\leq \Pr[A]\leq b$.

I tried to used the fact that
$$\Pr[A]=\Pr[A\cap B]+\Pr[A\cap \bar{B}]=0.2+\Pr[A\cap \bar{B}],$$
but I am not sure how to obtain a bound on $\Pr[A\cap \bar{B}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first observe that

$$(A\cap B)\cup(\overline{A}\cap B)=B$$

Thus

$$0.5< \mathbb{P}[B]< 0.6$$

and evidently

$$0.2\leq \mathbb{P}[A]\leq 0.7$$

here is a Venn's diagram showing the situation

[image]

Comment: How did you make the last step?

Comment: Why did you assume that $A\cup B=\Omega$?

Comment: @Illuminate : I beg your pardon, you are right. Added an amended diagram

Comment: Great, now it is fine. Thanks.